# How to deal with Gaussian Errors, which don't have a mean value of 0?

Tags: slam, data-association, gaussian

I'm writing a SLAM algorithm. One of the main problems is, that the landmark measurement error is not really Gaussian distributed, which means, their error doesn't have a mean value of 0.

I already tried other M-Estimators, but they all make the assumptions, that the error has a mean of 0. How do you cope with these problems? I think it is safe to say, that most measurements in real life are not gaussian distributed with a mean error of 0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is mathematically sound or not, but it's given me good results in practice. What I've done in this situation personally, when I expect/know that there is a bias, is to include the bias as a state in my state space representation of the system.

For example, if I have a system to track position, I might write the state space models like:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
\dot{x} \\
\ddot{x} \end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x} \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
K \end{matrix}\right] u
$$

So in this model, hypothetically, the input is maybe some motor torque through a gearbox to a wheel, so the input is a torque, some constant K converts it to an acceleration. Straightforward enough, but what if I *know* that I'm operating on an incline, but can't measure it? Or, if I know I'm testing on flat ground, but the event track will have an incline?

The trick here requires a bit of fundamental understanding of the differential equation - a differential equation tells you how the variable *changes*. So, if I expect the slope to be *constant* in the long-term ("long" relative to the other dynamics of the system), then I can get away with describing the *change* in slope as being zero! So I modify my state space representation to be:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
\dot{x} \\
\ddot{x} \\
\frac{d}{dt}\theta \end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -mg\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x} \\
\theta \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
K \\
0 \end{matrix}\right] u
$$

So where previously I was assuming the acceleration is some linear function of my input (torque):

$$
\ddot{x} = Ku \\
$$

Now I'm saying that the acceleration is the torque times a constant *minus the effect of the slope*:

$$
\ddot{x} = Ku - mg\theta \\
$$

This is a use of the small angle approximation $\sin\left(\theta\right) \approx \theta$.

Assuming I can measure position and speed, but not slope, this leaves me with the typical state-space matrices:

$$ 
A = \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -mg\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]
$$

and

$$
C = \left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \end{matrix}\right]
$$

and then I can check for [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability) in Matlab:

```
>> syms m g
>> A = [0, 1, 0; 0, 0, -m*g; 0, 0, 0];
>> C = [1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0];
>> O = [C; C*A; C*A*A];
>> rank(O)

ans =

     3
```

And so you can see that the bias-estimating state-space form **is observable**, meaning that it is possible to estimate the bias term (slope, in this example) just by measuring the position and speed of the vehicle.

Comment: This is actually the most common way to deal with biases in Kalman Filters so it is mathematically sound. Just add it as a parameter to the state vector.  Whenever you do IMU based estimation you add a bias parameter to the state vector for the accelerometer and gyroscope.

Comment: @edwinem - good to know, thanks! I had read about parameter estimation with Kalman filters before, but didn't know how common (or not) bias estimation is.

Comment: @edwinem it can be noted that the added bias state is not controllable, so when applying something like LQR or pole placement one needs to take a few extra steps in order to obtain a state feedback control policy.